# How can I make code-generation respect my formatting settings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, t4

I've started using VS2012's MVC project template, and I like how I can right-click and say "Add Controller" or "Add View" to produce new classes. But the generated class code doesn't respect the text formatting settings from `Tools > Options > text Editor > C# > Formatting`.

Specifically, the new line options for braces are all unchecked, and yet the generated class code puts all open braces on new lines.  Every time I first save the new class, it warns me about the mixed tabs and spaces (my settings say to keep tabs).

I suspect there are T4 templates backing these classes, but I don't know where to find them or how to edit them.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you want to start each opening brace at the end of the previous line.  You'd really be swimming upstream with that one; I know of no one who advocates that brace style with c#.

Comment: Fair enough.  Do you know of anyone who advises *against* it?  Can you give any reason why I would want to switch that doesn't amount to someone's justification of their personal preference?  

(Let me give you a hint: questions about which brace-style is best tend to get closed here as "not constructive"--rightly so, I think.)

Comment: Only the principle of least surprise.  That, and most shops are going to follow the style ingrained in Visual Studio, which puts the opening brace on its own line. You *are* going to follow the shop's already-established coding style, right? :)  If this is an open-source project, you *are* going to do it the way everyone else does it, right? :)

Comment: I come from a Java background, and I've been lead developer on this project for the past 5 years (during which time I convinced our gov't overlords to allow us to code in C# instead of Visual Barfsic).  So I got to set the formatting conventions.  Much of our code uses "Egyptian" braces already.  But some of us like to do it the other way.  Since I'm not a despot (and apparently have the super-human ability to read either brace style with ease), I don't require things to be one way or the other.  It's never been an issue.

Comment: So it's already the shop style.  Good for you.

Comment: Yup!  Which is what prompted the question in the first place.  Funny how it all comes full circle.  Look: can we just agree to disagree, and make fun of the poor sods who still have to use VB?  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the code is generated using T4 templates. You would have to modify those T4 templates to fit what you need.

- Here is [fantastic tutorial](http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/using-custom-t4-templates-to-generate-better-controllers-in-asp-mvc/) walking you through it.
- And here is [another article on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291528.aspx).
- And [yet another one](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/) by Steven Sanderson.